# sql statement to calculate the average for a selected set of values

Tags: sql

I am new to access and SQL statements.  I have two tables, Site_ID and SE_WaterQuality_Data.  For each site, several water quality parameters were collected over 5 weeks in summer and 5 weeks in winter.  I want to be able to run a query that will return a table that shows the average of a particular parameter (eg Temp) grouped by the Site_ID and the sample period (eg summer 2013).  I am close but my output table only shows the average value and not the site ID or sample period. The query also prompts the user to enter a particular Site_ID and I want it to run the query for all sites.

My SQL statement at the moment is

```
SELECT Avg(SE_WaterQuality_Data.[TEMP (C)]) AS [AvgOfTEMP (C)]
FROM SE_WaterQuality_Data
WHERE (((SE_WaterQuality_Data.EMS_ID)=[Site_ID].[EMS_ID]))
GROUP BY SE_WaterQuality_Data.EMS_ID, SE_WaterQuality_Data.SummaryPeriod;
```

And my output is

```
AveOFTEMP(C)

14.7
5.2
```

How can I change the SQL statement to 1) run the query for all sites and 2) return a table such as the one below:

Desired Output

```
Site_ID*      SamplePeriod*   AveTemp
1             Sum2013         14.2
1             Win2013         5.6
5             Sum2013         18.5
```

Help please......

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run for all sites, take out the `WHERE` clause. And if you want to show other columns, include them in your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT [EMS_ID] AS [Site_ID], 
       [SummaryPeriod] AS [Sample_Period],
       Avg(SE_WaterQuality_Data.[TEMP (C)]) AS [AvgOfTEMP (C)]
FROM SE_WaterQuality_Data
GROUP BY SE_WaterQuality_Data.EMS_ID, SE_WaterQuality_Data.SummaryPeriod;
```

I hope I got the syntax details right. I don't use SQL Server, I use MySQL. But the basic ideas are the same in all SQL dialects.

Comment: I just worked out the select to add more columns. Thanks for the advice to remove the where clause. That worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Site.Site_Id, WQ.SummaryPeriod, Avg(WQ.TEMP) AS AveTemp
FROM SE_WaterQuality_Data WQ, Site
WHERE WQ.EMS_ID   =   Site.EMS_ID
GROUP BY 1, 2
;
```